# coldfusion - file content editing

Tags: coldfusion, fckeditor, fw1

I've got [fw1](http://fw1.riaforge.org/) using the content of the default.cfm page as the editable content region. While this works fine for static content, I'd like to add the ability to edit the content over with fckeditor or some other in-browser WYSIWYG tool.

Is there any tool you could recommend that would make this easy? I don't want to convert to a CMS like mura, just want to login and the ability to edit the contents of about 5 files, with the possibility of creating a timestamped backup of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the concept of a dynamic text area on some pages on applications that don't require a full on cms.

This is with ColdBox, but you should be able to implement something similar in fw1.

We have a helper component with a method that allows us to "render dynamic text" with a specific code eg. "helppagetext" in a zone in the page. We then have a very simple CRUD application using CKEditor that saves text blocks against those codes. The CRUD application is protected by a pre-existing login system.

It is pretty simple to implement something like this, especially if you already have a security and login system in place.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

ColdFusion 8 and above has a built in WSYIWYG editor. It is a part of `<cftextarea`

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_t_02.html